# Distribution of cycles length in a graph

Tags: graphs, combinatorics

Given a random **directed** Graph G:

$$
 G=(V,E) \\
 \lvert V \rvert = n , \lvert E \rvert = k
$$

where for each vertex, **either**:
$$
  d_{incoming}(v) = 1 , d_{outgoing}(v) = 1
$$
meaning - for each incoming (outgoing) edge to vertex v, there is also an outgoing (incoming) edge from vertex v.

Or:
$$
d(v) = 0
$$

What is the distribution of lengths of the longest cycles for this set of random graphs?

This question relates to the [riddle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eivGlBKlK6M&list=UUUHW94eEFW7hkUMVaZz4eDg) presented in the last minute-physics video. (for the general case)

Comment: Nice question. If it doesn't get an answer here after a few days, you should maybe flag it for migration to [math.se]. But please don't just repost it there as doing so will fragment answers and confuse people.

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? What are your thoughts and motivations for this question?

Comment: @DavidRicherby "Nice" as in interesting, but certainly not SE-nice, isn't it? Do you see how to flesh it out?

Comment: @Raphael Does it need fleshing out? A brief survey of existing results in the field would be a reasonable answer. For example, Pósa has shown that, for a large enough constant $c$, a random graph with $n$ vertices and $cn\log n$ edges is asymptotically almost surely Hamiltonian ("Hamilton circuits in random graphs", *Discrete Mathematics*, 14:359-364, 1976).

Comment: @DavidRicherby Can you provide an answer then? I'm not sure whether the question asks for an algorithm (text) or a "static" result (tags).

Comment: @Raphael I can't answer the question as I don't know enough about random graphs. I found the Pósa paper only because I knew there are results about Hamiltonicity of random graphs, which is clearly relevant but is a long way from a good answer.

Comment: "Either $d_{\mathrm{in}}(v)=1$ or $d_{\mathrm{out}}(v)$=1" does *not* mean that there is an incoming edge for each outgoing edge. It means that either there is exactly one incoming edge or exactly one outgoing edge.

Comment: Hi David, its not an *or*, but an *and*. Does it make sense now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When $k = n$ and self-loops are allowed, what you have is a *random permutation*. The expected length of the longest cycle in a permutation is known to be $\alpha n$ for $\alpha \approx 0.624$, see [Shepp and Lloyd](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1966-121-02/S0002-9947-1966-0195117-8/S0002-9947-1966-0195117-8.pdf). If self-loops are not allowed then you will get a different constant $\beta$ that can probably be computed using the methods of Shepp and Lloyd.

When $k < n$, you just get a permutation on $k$ vertices, so instead of $\alpha n$ or $\beta n$ you would get $\alpha k$ or $\beta k$.